# Why am I getting a "line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'" error in bash script?

Tags: bash, unix, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a function in bash:

```
check_for_file()
{
if [ $1 = '' ]; then
        local testing_file = myproject
elif
        local testing_file = $1
fi

if [ -d testing_file ]; then
        echo "Directory name already exists"
        exit
elif
        mkdir -p testing_file/{archive,backups,docs/html,docs/txt,assets,database,src/sh,src/c}
fi
return
}
```

But when I run it I get the following output:
./mkproj.sh: line 10: syntax error near unexpected token `fi' ./mkproj.sh: line 10:` fi'

Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: `elif` requires an additional condition. You just want `else`.

Comment: As an aside, it's `mkdir -p "$testing_file"/...`. You aren't currently expanding the variable to its value for `mkdir` to use.

Comment: As chepner said, the condition in the `elif` is missing, **but** you also need a `then`. See the bash manpage, which describes the `if` statement as: `if list; then list; [ elif list; then list; ] ... [ else list; ] fi`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`elif` expects another command to test. Formatting aside, `local testing_file = $1` is treated as that condition, but then the keyword `fi` is seen before the expected `then` keyword.

Use `else` instead:

```
if [ $1 = '' ]; then
        local testing_file=myproject
else
        local testing_file=$1
fi
```

(Note, too, that you cannot put spaces around the `=` in the assignments.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `then` after the `elif` statement
But your statement is also wrong because `elif` needs a command to test

So in your case, just use the `else` instead.